# Elasticsearch aggregation buckets always showing only 10 results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using Elasticsearch aggregation for load data, when passing offset count the response results are showing correctly but terms aggregation results/buckets always showing only 10 results.

```
Map<String, BucketStats> hourAggregations = new HashMap<>();
    SearchResponse getResponse = client.prepareSearch( ElasticSearchConstants.INDEX ).setTypes( ElasticSearchConstants.TABLE)
            .addAggregation( AggregationBuilders.terms( "name")
                    .field( "empId" )
                    .subAggregation( AggregationBuilders.stats( "stats" )
            .setQuery( query )
            .setFrom( 0 )
            .setSize( ( offset + 1 ) * 10 )
            .execute().actionGet();

    Terms terms = getResponse.getAggregations().get("name");
    for ( Terms.Bucket bucket : terms.getBuckets() )
    {
    //buckets showing only 10 results
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a size to your `terms` aggregation:

```
Map<String, BucketStats> hourAggregations = new HashMap<>();
SearchResponse getResponse = client.prepareSearch( ElasticSearchConstants.INDEX ).setTypes( ElasticSearchConstants.TABLE)
        .addAggregation( AggregationBuilders.terms( "name")
                .field( "empId" )
-->             .size(100)
                .subAggregation( AggregationBuilders.stats( "stats" )
        .setQuery( query )
        .setFrom( 0 )
        .setSize( ( offset + 1 ) * 10 )
        .execute().actionGet();
```

The `setSize()` call only impacts the `hits` section, i.e. the document set in the results, not the aggregations. The way I see it you should call `setSize(0)`, because you only want aggregation values and not documents.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.
I put (offset +1)*10 as for size and its works now.